# Fixed sidebar, scrollable content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a webpage that will have a fixed sidebar and scrollable content. It does work if I don't have a header div. If I scroll page I have some empty space that previously was a header (i marked it with red color). I'd like my sidebar to cover the empty space after I scroll through header div.

Here's my HTML Code - how can I fix this?

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"type=" text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">

        <div id="header">   
        </div>

        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#news">news</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="abcd">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#page
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:3000px;

    background-color:yellow;
}

#header
{
    background-color: blue;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
}

#navigation
{

    background-color: red;
    width:10%;  
    height:3000px;
    float:left;

}

#content
{
    float:left;
    background-color: green;
    width:90%;  
    overflow: auto;
    height:1000px;
}

body 
{
    margin: 0;
}

ul 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a 
{
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place your navigation div in outermost part i.e. in body(not in any other div).

I have tested this and its now working fine.

Your new code should be

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type=" text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">news</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="page">

        <div id="header">

        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="abcd">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And your modified css:-

```
#page {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3000px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#header {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
}

#navigation
{
    background-color: red;
    width:10%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 1000px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

In css I have changed the navigation's height to 100% and its z-index to 1.

Also you didn't close the div tag with class "page".

Reference:- w3 css [sidenav](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_sidenav)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think that my question was not quite accurate. I want my navigation bar to cover full height of the page (also I want these list items to be on the top of the page) when I scroll trough header div.

Comment: I have updated my answer and inserted the working code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
#navigation {
    background-color: red;
    width: 10%;
    height: 3000px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately it covers my navigation bar, I want it to cover full page only when I can't see header.